# How do I align a div to the bottom while still allowing scrolling?

Tags: css, layout

I have a chatbox, fixed at the bottom of a div with `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0px;`.
The problem with this however, is that it's not scrollable. How would I make that happen?

-Edit- It's on the bottom of this page: http://www.novaember.com/servers/minecraft/

Comment: What's not scrollable? Please provide your code or an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like so:

```
#chatdiv {
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: This won't work, because the chatbox is higher than the containing div. I'll add the page I'm working on to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something in the page you gave. And I guess I got what you're asking by adding `height: 285px` and `overflow-y: scroll` to `#webchat-messages`.

Comment: This works, but it will start at the top of the log. Is using Javascript the only option to fix this?

Comment: It works also with "height: 100%" which is better than hardcoding pixels.

Answer (score 0):

We want to force the div to accept the height of its parent div. Use `top:0` should allow it:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
overflow-y: scroll;
```